# Sidekiq::Rails:Class overrides default Rails class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sidekiq

Sidekiq::Rails:Class override global Rails::Class

I'm trying to call the Rails.cache method but i get an error "undefined method `cache' for Sidekiq::Rails:Class". I check in the debugger and i found that 'Rails'class type in this method is the Sidekiq::Rails:Class and not the default Rails:Class. I think that in runtime sidekiq overrided the Rails main class.

```
  def index
  ##
     ## >>>>>> Rails here is identified as Sidekiq::Rails:Class
     @cities = Rails.cache.fetch("cities", :expires_in => 10.days) do
       City.all
     end
     render :json => {:list => @cities}
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to refer to 'root' `Rails` class, which is possible with `::`:

```
::Rails.cache.fetch('cities', express_in: 10.days) do
  # ...
```

To extend my answer, if you have something like:

```
module Sidekiq
  # body
end
```

it sets the default namespace for the whole `body` to `Sidekiq`, so if you want to refer to some constant inside of it, like you did with `Rails`, Ruby searches for `Sidekiq::Rails` first and then goes up the namespace hierarchy, searching for `::Rails`.

Comment: That's works, thank you !
 But, should i use the Rails class this way (root declaration) all over the code ?

Comment: @HoussemFat, no, not really, which explains my edited answer. You have to use `::` only when there's an ambiguocity in constant name resolution.

Comment: Ok, it seems a little weird that sidekiq team use same constant used in a global Rails application. Thank you for your reply !